# Where is the standard mapping from Java Object types to SQL types defined?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

In the [JDBC docs of `setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-) I found this sentence:

> The JDBC specification specifies a standard mapping from Java Object
>   types to SQL types.

However, I cannot find where this mapping is defined. All I found is [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html). But that only specifies the mapping between SQL types and JDBC types. But I don't see, how I get from JDBC type to Java types.

More specifically, I'm wondering if e.g. this code is guaranteed to never throw an `InvalidCastException`:

```
int type = resultSet.getMetadata().getColumnType(1);
if (type == Types.LONGNVARCHAR || type == Types.CHAR) {
    String abc = (String)resultSet.getObject(1);
}
```

In this case it's quite intuitive that one would expect `String`, but there are many other SQL types for which I don't have such an intuition.

I just cannot find a table telling me which casts can be safely performed based on the knowledge of the `java.sql.Types` constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the official spec for JDBC [here](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/index.html) (since you link to Java 8 documentation, the spec would be for JDBC version 4.2). Specifically it is in table B-3 in the appendices.

For the JDBC types `CHAR` and `LONGNVARCHAR`, the Java type is indeed `String` so your cast is safe.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Also thanks for the index correction. I fixed that in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the type mappings here:

[Mapping SQL and Java Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html) (Java 1.5)

The part you're looking for is in table 8.9.3 JDBC Types Mapped to Java Object Types:

> ```
> JDBC Type       Java Object Type
> =============   ==============================
> CHAR            String
> VARCHAR         String
> LONGVARCHAR     String
> NUMERIC         java.math.BigDecimal
> DECIMAL         java.math.BigDecimal
> BIT             Boolean
> TINYINT         Integer
> SMALLINT        Integer
> INTEGER         Integer
> BIGINT          Long
> REAL            Float
> FLOAT           Double
> DOUBLE          Double
> BINARY          byte[]
> VARBINARY       byte[]
> LONGVARBINARY   byte[]
> DATE            java.sql.Date
> TIME            java.sql.Time
> TIMESTAMP       java.sql.Timestamp
> DISTINCT        Object type of underlying type
> CLOB            Clob
> BLOB            Blob
> ARRAY           Array
> STRUCT          Struct or SQLData
> REF             Ref
> JAVA_OBJECT     underlying Java class
> ```

Comment: Wonder if there is a more recent one... This looks very old.

Comment: @manouti Most recent I could find online on Oracle's site. Never ones are download only, see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54891470/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Mybatis Generator source code URL:

https://github.com/mybatis/generator/blob/fe8232ad26214e06d349f697ffb67ec09036a842/core/mybatis-generator-core/src/main/java/org/mybatis/generator/internal/types/JavaTypeResolverDefaultImpl.java

Here is the copy of source code(Prevent URL to be invalid)

```java
/*
 *    Copyright 2006-2020 the original author or authors.
 *
 *    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *    You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *    limitations under the License.
 */
package org.mybatis.generator.internal.types;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.mybatis.generator.api.IntrospectedColumn;
import org.mybatis.generator.api.JavaTypeResolver;
import org.mybatis.generator.api.dom.java.FullyQualifiedJavaType;
import org.mybatis.generator.config.Context;
import org.mybatis.generator.config.PropertyRegistry;
import org.mybatis.generator.internal.util.StringUtility;

public class JavaTypeResolverDefaultImpl implements JavaTypeResolver {

    protected List<String> warnings;

    protected final Properties properties;

    protected Context context;

    protected boolean forceBigDecimals;
    protected boolean useJSR310Types;

    protected final Map<Integer, JdbcTypeInformation> typeMap;

    public JavaTypeResolverDefaultImpl() {
        super();
        properties = new Properties();
        typeMap = new HashMap<>();

        typeMap.put(Types.ARRAY, new JdbcTypeInformation("ARRAY", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Object.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.BIGINT, new JdbcTypeInformation("BIGINT", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Long.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.BINARY, new JdbcTypeInformation("BINARY", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType("byte[]"))); //$NON-NLS-1$
        typeMap.put(Types.BIT, new JdbcTypeInformation("BIT", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Boolean.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.BLOB, new JdbcTypeInformation("BLOB", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType("byte[]"))); //$NON-NLS-1$
        typeMap.put(Types.BOOLEAN, new JdbcTypeInformation("BOOLEAN", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Boolean.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.CHAR, new JdbcTypeInformation("CHAR", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(String.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.CLOB, new JdbcTypeInformation("CLOB", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(String.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.DATALINK, new JdbcTypeInformation("DATALINK", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Object.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.DATE, new JdbcTypeInformation("DATE", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Date.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.DECIMAL, new JdbcTypeInformation("DECIMAL", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(BigDecimal.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.DISTINCT, new JdbcTypeInformation("DISTINCT", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Object.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.DOUBLE, new JdbcTypeInformation("DOUBLE", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Double.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.FLOAT, new JdbcTypeInformation("FLOAT", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Double.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.INTEGER, new JdbcTypeInformation("INTEGER", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Integer.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, new JdbcTypeInformation("JAVA_OBJECT", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Object.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.LONGNVARCHAR, new JdbcTypeInformation("LONGNVARCHAR", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(String.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.LONGVARBINARY, new JdbcTypeInformation(
                "LONGVARBINARY", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType("byte[]"))); //$NON-NLS-1$
        typeMap.put(Types.LONGVARCHAR, new JdbcTypeInformation("LONGVARCHAR", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(String.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.NCHAR, new JdbcTypeInformation("NCHAR", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(String.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.NCLOB, new JdbcTypeInformation("NCLOB", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(String.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.NVARCHAR, new JdbcTypeInformation("NVARCHAR", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(String.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.NULL, new JdbcTypeInformation("NULL", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Object.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.NUMERIC, new JdbcTypeInformation("NUMERIC", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(BigDecimal.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.OTHER, new JdbcTypeInformation("OTHER", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Object.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.REAL, new JdbcTypeInformation("REAL", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Float.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.REF, new JdbcTypeInformation("REF", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Object.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.SMALLINT, new JdbcTypeInformation("SMALLINT", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Short.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.STRUCT, new JdbcTypeInformation("STRUCT", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Object.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.TIME, new JdbcTypeInformation("TIME", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Date.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.TIMESTAMP, new JdbcTypeInformation("TIMESTAMP", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Date.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.TINYINT, new JdbcTypeInformation("TINYINT", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Byte.class.getName())));
        typeMap.put(Types.VARBINARY, new JdbcTypeInformation("VARBINARY", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType("byte[]"))); //$NON-NLS-1$
        typeMap.put(Types.VARCHAR, new JdbcTypeInformation("VARCHAR", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType(String.class.getName())));
        // JDK 1.8 types
        typeMap.put(Types.TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE, new JdbcTypeInformation("TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType("java.time.OffsetTime"))); //$NON-NLS-1$
        typeMap.put(Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE, new JdbcTypeInformation("TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE", //$NON-NLS-1$
                new FullyQualifiedJavaType("java.time.OffsetDateTime"))); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void addConfigurationProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties.putAll(properties);
        forceBigDecimals = StringUtility
                .isTrue(properties
                        .getProperty(PropertyRegistry.TYPE_RESOLVER_FORCE_BIG_DECIMALS));
        useJSR310Types = StringUtility
                .isTrue(properties
                        .getProperty(PropertyRegistry.TYPE_RESOLVER_USE_JSR310_TYPES));
    }

    @Override
    public FullyQualifiedJavaType calculateJavaType(
            IntrospectedColumn introspectedColumn) {
        FullyQualifiedJavaType answer = null;
        JdbcTypeInformation jdbcTypeInformation = typeMap
                .get(introspectedColumn.getJdbcType());

        if (jdbcTypeInformation != null) {
            answer = jdbcTypeInformation.getFullyQualifiedJavaType();
            answer = overrideDefaultType(introspectedColumn, answer);
        }

        return answer;
    }

    protected FullyQualifiedJavaType overrideDefaultType(IntrospectedColumn column,
            FullyQualifiedJavaType defaultType) {
        FullyQualifiedJavaType answer = defaultType;

        switch (column.getJdbcType()) {
        case Types.BIT:
            answer = calculateBitReplacement(column, defaultType);
            break;
        case Types.DATE:
            answer = calculateDateType(column, defaultType);
            break;
        case Types.DECIMAL:
        case Types.NUMERIC:
            answer = calculateBigDecimalReplacement(column, defaultType);
            break;
        case Types.TIME:
            answer = calculateTimeType(column, defaultType);
            break;
        case Types.TIMESTAMP:
            answer = calculateTimestampType(column, defaultType);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        return answer;
    }

    protected FullyQualifiedJavaType calculateDateType(IntrospectedColumn column, FullyQualifiedJavaType defaultType) {
        FullyQualifiedJavaType answer;

        if (useJSR310Types) {
            answer = new FullyQualifiedJavaType("java.time.LocalDate"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        } else {
            answer = defaultType;
        }

        return answer;
    }

    protected FullyQualifiedJavaType calculateTimeType(IntrospectedColumn column, FullyQualifiedJavaType defaultType) {
        FullyQualifiedJavaType answer;

        if (useJSR310Types) {
            answer = new FullyQualifiedJavaType("java.time.LocalTime"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        } else {
            answer = defaultType;
        }

        return answer;
    }

    protected FullyQualifiedJavaType calculateTimestampType(IntrospectedColumn column,
            FullyQualifiedJavaType defaultType) {
        FullyQualifiedJavaType answer;

        if (useJSR310Types) {
            answer = new FullyQualifiedJavaType("java.time.LocalDateTime"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        } else {
            answer = defaultType;
        }

        return answer;
    }

    protected FullyQualifiedJavaType calculateBitReplacement(IntrospectedColumn column,
            FullyQualifiedJavaType defaultType) {
        FullyQualifiedJavaType answer;

        if (column.getLength() > 1) {
            answer = new FullyQualifiedJavaType("byte[]"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        } else {
            answer = defaultType;
        }

        return answer;
    }

    protected FullyQualifiedJavaType calculateBigDecimalReplacement(IntrospectedColumn column,
            FullyQualifiedJavaType defaultType) {
        FullyQualifiedJavaType answer;

        if (column.getScale() > 0 || column.getLength() > 18 || forceBigDecimals) {
            answer = defaultType;
        } else if (column.getLength() > 9) {
            answer = new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Long.class.getName());
        } else if (column.getLength() > 4) {
            answer = new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Integer.class.getName());
        } else {
            answer = new FullyQualifiedJavaType(Short.class.getName());
        }

        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    public String calculateJdbcTypeName(IntrospectedColumn introspectedColumn) {
        String answer = null;
        JdbcTypeInformation jdbcTypeInformation = typeMap
                .get(introspectedColumn.getJdbcType());

        if (jdbcTypeInformation != null) {
            answer = jdbcTypeInformation.getJdbcTypeName();
        }

        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWarnings(List<String> warnings) {
        this.warnings = warnings;
    }

    @Override
    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class JdbcTypeInformation {
        private final String jdbcTypeName;

        private final FullyQualifiedJavaType fullyQualifiedJavaType;

        public JdbcTypeInformation(String jdbcTypeName,
                FullyQualifiedJavaType fullyQualifiedJavaType) {
            this.jdbcTypeName = jdbcTypeName;
            this.fullyQualifiedJavaType = fullyQualifiedJavaType;
        }

        public String getJdbcTypeName() {
            return jdbcTypeName;
        }

        public FullyQualifiedJavaType getFullyQualifiedJavaType() {
            return fullyQualifiedJavaType;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31858342)